What is the best machine learning textbook for decision trees?
What is the best machine learning textbook for decision trees, where theory and
practice are balanced?

Favorite of mine:
"Tree-based Machine Learning Algorithms: Decision Trees, Random Forests, and Boosting" by Ding-Zhu Du and Ker-I Ko

Reviewer comments about this book in Amazon are not so good.
